# ARM assembly quicksort and recursion

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to change C quick sort code to ARM assembly code.
Firstly, I apologize for my long question.
just in case, I wrote whole codes.
but only part that makes problem is function recursion part.
I almost done this work except funcion recursion part.
I've also tried converting C codes to ARM assembly with gcc cross compiler to see how compiler do. But there are still few things that I can't understand well.

This is C code.

```
void quicksort_c(int array[8],int first,int last)
{
int i, j, pivot, temp;

if(first < last)
{
    pivot = first;
    i = first;
    j = last;

    while(i < j)
    {
        while(array[i] <= array[pivot] && i < last)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while(array[j] > array[pivot])
        {
            j--;
        }
        if(i < j)
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }


    temp = array[pivot];
    array[pivot] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
    quicksort_c(array, first, j-1);
    quicksort_c(array, j+1, last);
}
}
```

and this is arm assembly code that I wrote from scratch.

```
quicksort
    STMFD sp!, {r0-r8,lr}

quicksort_recursion
    CMP r1, r2 ;// if(first < last)
    BGE out_of_if

outer_if
    MOV r5, r1 ;// pivot = first
    MOV r3, r1 ;// i = first;
    MOV r4, r2 ;// j = last;

outer_while_loop
    CMP r3, r4 ;// while(i < j)
    BGE end_of_outer_while

outer_while

inner_while_1_loop
    ;//while(array[i] <= array[pivot] && i < last)
    LDR r7, [r0, r3, lsl #2] ;//r7 = array[i]
    LDR r8, [r0, r5, lsl #2] ;//r8 = array[pivot]

    CMP r7, r8 ;//array[i] <= array[pivot]
    BGT inner_while_2_loop

    CMP r3, r2 ;// i < last
    BGE inner_while_2_loop

inner_while_1
    ADD r3, #1 ;//i++
    B   inner_while_1_loop

inner_while_2_loop
    ;//whlie(array[j] > array[pivot])
    LDR r7, [r0, r4, lsl #2] ;// r7 = array[j]
    LDR r8, [r0, r5, lsl #2] ;//r8 = array[pivot]

    CMP r7, r8 ;// (array[j] > array[pivot])
    BLE inner_if_cmp

inner_while_2
    SUB r4, #1
    B   inner_while_2_loop

inner_if_cmp
    CMP r3, r4;// if(i < j)
    BGE outer_while_loop

inner_if
    LDR r7, [r0, r3, lsl #2] ;// r7 = array[i]
    MOV r6, r7 ;// temp = array[i]

    LDR r8, [r0, r4, lsl #2] ;// r8 = array[j]
    STR r8, [r0, r3, lsl #2] ;// array[i] = array[j]

    STR r6, [r0, r4, lsl #2] ;// array[j] = temp;

    B   outer_while_loop

end_of_outer_while
    LDR r7, [r0, r5, lsl #2] ;// r7 = array[pivot]
    MOV r6, r7 ;// temp = array[pivot]

    LDR r8, [r0, r4, lsl #2] ;// r8 = array[j]
    STR r8, [r0, r5, lsl #2] ;// array[pivot] = array[j]

    STR r6, [r0, r4, lsl #2] ;// array[j] = temp

    ;;//quicksort(array,first,j-1)
    STMFD sp!, {r0-r8,lr}
    SUBS    r2, r4, #1
    BL  quicksort_recursion
    ;//LDMFD sp!, {r0-r8,pc}


    ;//quicksort(array, j+1, last)
    STMFD sp!, {r0-r8,lr}
    ADDS    r1, r4, #1
    BL  quicksort_recursion
    ;//LDMFD sp!, {r0-r8,pc}

out_of_if

end_function
    LDMFD sp!, {r0-r8,pc}
    END
```

and this is how I use register

```
r0: array pointer
r1: first index
r2: last index

r3: i
r4: j
r5: pivot
r6: temp

r7: array[?] value
r8: array[?] value
```

I confirmed every parts except recursion of my code are work well.

At first, I did recursion in this way.

```
;;//quicksort(array,first,j-1)
SUBS    r2, r4, #1
BL  quicksort

;//quicksort(array, j+1, last)
ADDS    r1, r4, #1
BL  quicksort
```

but this code only do first function recursion.

ex)
Array before quicksorting : 5 1 4 7 8 3 6
Array after quicksorting : 1 2 4 3 5 8 7 6

I think it's because after function call, it doesn't go back to where it branched. so I added push and pop before and after function call like this.

```
;;//quicksort(array,first,j-1)
STMFD sp!, {r0-r8,lr}
SUBS    r2, r4, #1
BL  quicksort_recursion

;//quicksort(array, j+1, last)
STMFD sp!, {r0-r8,lr}
ADDS    r1, r4, #1
BL  quicksort_recursion
```

But this code falls in to infinite loop.

according to gcc compiled code,

```
quicksort_linux
    cmp r1, r2
    blt L16
    bx  lr
L16
    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, lr}
    mov r10, r1
    add ip, r0, r1, lsl #2
    mov r5, r2
    mov r4, r1
L3
    lsls    r3, r4, #2
    add lr, r0, r3
    ldr r7, [r0, r4, lsl #2]
    ldr r6, [ip]
    cmp r2, r4
    ite le
    movle   r8, #0
    movgt   r8, #1
    cmp r7, r6
    it  gt
    movgt   r8, #0
    adds    r3, r3, #4
    add r3, r3, r0
    cmp r8, #0
    beq L9
L4
    adds    r4, r4, #1
    mov lr, r3
    ldr r7, [r3], #4
    cmp r2, r4
    ite le
    movle   r1, #0
    movgt   r1, #1
    cmp r7, r6
    it  gt
    movgt   r1, #0
    cmp r1, #0
    bne L4
L9
    lsls    r3, r5, #2
    add r9, r0, r3
    ldr r1, [r0, r5, lsl #2]
    cmp r1, r6
    ble L5
    subs    r3, r3, #4
    add r3, r3, r0
L6
    subs    r5, r5, #1
    mov r9, r3
    ldr r1, [r3], #-4
    cmp r1, r6
    bgt L6
L5
    cmp r4, r5
    bge L7
    str r1, [lr]
    str r7, [r9]
    b   L3
L7
    mov r7, r2
    mov r1, r10
    mov r4, r0
    ldr r3, [r0, r5, lsl #2]
    str r3, [r0, r10, lsl #2]
    str r6, [r0, r5, lsl #2]
    subs    r2, r5, #1
    bl  quicksort_linux
    mov r2, r7
    adds    r1, r5, #1
    mov r0, r4
    bl  quicksort_linux
    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, pc}

END
```

It seems like they don't do any push or pop before or after branch but it works.

So, question is
1.what is problem of my function recursion code?
2.How can I fix that?
3.How can gcc compiled code works without any push and pop before and after function recursion?

Comment: _"so I added push and pop"_ according to what you showed you did not add the pop so it won't work. In the big code the pop is there but commented out. It's unclear what is the exact version you are running.

Comment: If I don't comment out, it doesn't do infinite loop, but it showed totally wrong result 0 7 744 0 7 0 0 0

Comment: if I comment out pop part, it falls to infinite loop. If I comment out both push and pop, it only do first recursion.

Comment: You need both push and pop (in your version). So use that and debug it why the result is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I found what is problem. And it is solved.